# Como esconder FloatingActionButton cuando se abre el teclado al presionar sobre un EditText?

Tags: android

necesito saber alguna forma de esconder un boton flotante cuando accedo a un EditText y se abre el teclado, y de qué forma también se lo puede esconder cuando "Scrolleo" la pantalla.

Answer (score 0):

Prueba lo siguiente

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getActivity()
            .getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);

    if (imm.isAcceptingText()) {
        floatingButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    } else {
        floatingButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
```